# SignalR wont load signalr/hubs in IIS in ASP.Net web app

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have a simnple example signalR app that works fine using the VS Development Studio server, however it fails to work when I switch to using IIS.

I have tried all versions of the declaration of the script for it,

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/TestApp/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All to no avail. It still sees /signalr/hubs as a 404 error when using the developer tools in chrome or IE. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I already have the line

`GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IConnectionIdGenerator), () => new MyConnectionFactory());`

In the Application_Start of the global.ascx . but it seems a tho some initialisation is not happening server side.

p.s. this is asp.net NOT asp MVC.

Comment: Do you have `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` in the Application_Start in the global.asax?

Comment: No Joy with that, as if I do attempt that RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); I get cannot resolve symbol MapHubs !

Comment: Did you add the `using SignalR;`?  MapHubs is an extension method from SignalR.